# how to change recursive method into non recursive one in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, tree

I wrote a small code to load followers tree from GitHub.

It is working well for my recursive version but i cannot get my "stack-que" version running.

I receive my response after I finish my loop which is the problem ;my recursive solution uses the same loadFollowers method but because of its structure of calls it produces the desired tree.

Should I somehow switch async off in my call?

```
function loadFollowers(user,field,callback){
  path = 'https://api.github.com/users/'+user.info[field]+'/followers';
  path += '?client_id=' + pass.client_id + '&client_secret='+pass.client_secret

  console.log("path:"+path+' field: '+field+' node: '+user);

  $.get(path,function(followers){
    for(var i = 0;i < followers.length; i++){ 
      current = new Node();
      current.info = followers[i];
      user.addFollower(current);
      callback();
    };
  });
}

function loadNetworkNonROld(node,depth,field){
var toVisit = [];
var visited =[];
var deep;
var current;
var curr;

  toVisit.push([node,depth]); // saves [node,level] to control how deep it is 
                              // starts at initial node

  while (toVisit.length > 0){   
      curr = toVisit.shift();
      current = curr[0];
      deep = curr[1];
      if((visited.indexOf(current.info[field])===-1) && (deep > 0)){
        visited.push(current.info[field]);
        loadFollowers(current,field,function(){ 
            for(var i=0;i < current.followers.length; i++){
              toVisit.push([current.followers[i],deep-1]);
            }
        });
      }  
  }
  return visited;  
}
```

recursive version which works just fine is below:

```
function loadNetwork(node,depth,field){

  loadFollowers(node,field,function(){
  if (depth == 0){return;}
  for(var i=0; i < node.followers.length; i++){
    current = node.followers[i];
    id = current.info[field];
    if (networkAllUsers.indexOf(id)===-1)
    { 
      networkAllUsers.push(id);
      console.log(id);
      loadNetwork(current,depth-1,field);
    }  
  }});
}
```

github link is:  https://github.com/marcinwal/myownnode.git
and the code is in public/javascript/main.js file.

Comment: Where is the problem code? You show function `loadNetworkNonROld()` but it never gets used. Also mention `stack-que` but what is that? Overall question is not clear whatsoever. It is never a good idea to use `async:false`

Comment: it is used in $('#formdepth').on('submit',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  depth = $('#depth').val();
  // loadNetwork(user,depth,'login');
  networkAllUsers = loadNetworkNonROld(user,depth,'login')
});

Comment: Can you tell why you want to use a non-recursive function when you already have a recursive one that does exacly what you want?

Comment: recursive is more expensive especially for bigger trees and i would like to have both solutions available;

Comment: Recursive is not more expensive, at least in this situation it's the least of your worries. If you have something that works, use it. If you want to sink your time into something, modify your tree for lazy/on-demand loading instead of pre-populating N levels.

Comment: My github repo is  https://github.com/marcinwal/myownnode.git; code which I meant is in public/javascript/main folder; My idea was to learn how to solve such problems in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly looks like the problem may well be the async running of loadFollowers in the iterative version.

However the key issue with your question is that while you show us the code, you don't show us the error you encountered, and you don't say what 'stack-que' is or respond to the comment asking for clarification.

Furthermore, you don't give us instructions about how to run your code to replicate the issue you encountered.  Reviewing your code I took a series of guesses, and you can see some of the results in this screen shot:

[image: screen shot of trying to replicate the error]

and I properly indented your iterative code, and added some logging that produces part of the above output:

```
function loadNetworkNonROld(node,depth,field){
  var toVisit = [];
  var visited =[];
  var deep;
  var current;
  var curr;

  toVisit.push([node,depth]); // saves [node,level] to control how deep it is 
                              // starts at initial node

  while (toVisit.length > 0){  
      console.log(toVisit) 
      curr = toVisit.shift();
      current = curr[0];
      deep = curr[1];
      if((visited.indexOf(current.info[field])===-1) && (deep > 0)){
        visited.push(current.info[field]);
        console.log(visited) 
        loadFollowers(current,field,function(){ 
          for(var i=0;i < current.followers.length; i++){
            toVisit.push([current.followers[i],deep-1]);
            console.log('loadFollowers:' + toVisit) 
          }
        });
      }  
  }
  return visited;  
}
```

Now I could spend further effort kicking around your code, guessing whether there's some output that we get, what have you, but you're not making it easy for people to help.

From what I see in the console log it looks to me like you are pushing all your nodes on at depth 1 and they are never reaching depth 0 so it's just running on and on forever.  Whereas in the recursive version the depth gets to 0.

I modified your code like so:

```
  while (toVisit.length > 0){  
      console.log(toVisit) 
      curr = toVisit.shift();
      current = curr[0];
      deep = curr[1];
      if((visited.indexOf(current.info[field])===-1) && (deep > 0)){
        visited.push(current.info[field]);
        console.log('loadNetworkNonROld: '+deep);
        loadFollowers(current,field,deep,function(depth){ 
          console.log('loadFollowers:' + (depth-1));
          for(var i=0;i < current.followers.length; i++){
            toVisit.push([current.followers[i],(depth-1)]);
          }
        });
      }  
  }
  console.log('loadNetworkNonROld: visited:'+JSON.stringify(visited));
  return visited;  
}
```

with parallel changes to the loadFollowers function so the depth value is actually passed along.  Now the code runs without iterating forever, but the asynchronous nature of javascript means that the result is returned before any of the network calls finished - hence the visited result is only ever the first user.

Comment: you are welcome - please click as correct if it's the right answer